# Codeigniter Query Builder dispatched in several functions

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, query-builder

I'm using Codeigniter 3.0.3.
I want to build a query with query builder but to split the build of my query in several functions. 
For example :

```
 class MyCart{

 public function __construct() {
    $this->db->select('A.id, A.title, A.price');
    $this->db->from('articles A');
 }

 public function check_type($aTypeOfArticle){
    $this->db->where("A.type=".$aTypeOfArticle);
 }

 public function check_price($aMaxPrice){
    $this->db->where("A.price<=".$aMaxPrice);
 }

 public function get_result(){
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
 }

}
```

But when I try this, `this->db->get()` returns false.
Is it possible to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

This would more than likely work better for you,

```
public function query()
{
  $this->db->select('A.id, A.title, A.price');
  $this->db->from('articles A');

  if( check_type($aTypeOfArticle) )
  {
    $this->db->where("A.type=".$aTypeOfArticle);
  }

  if( check_price($aMaxPrice) )
  {
    $this->db->where("A.price<=".$aMaxPrice);
  }
}

public function check_type($aTypeOfArticle){
  // Do processing
  return true or false;
}

public function check_price($aMaxPrice){
  // Do Processing
  return true or false;
}
```

Build the query in the single function and call the other function for the result of the processing.

Comment: So it is not possible to split the query in differents functions? Because I've got a lot of criteria to check and putting them all in the same function will be quite ugly.

Comment: Not that I know of, but that's not saying there isn't, I just don't know of any way.  I would say that the way I have shown is the way in which we do it here.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Method Chaining](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=query%20builder#method-chaining). You should be able to cache return value of the `from()` call (in the object property e.g.), then use that value to chain other methods on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Codeigniter Query builder Cache like `$this->db->start_cache()` and `$this->db->stop_cache()`. Check the [Documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#query-builder-caching) for more details

```
class MyCart{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->db->start_cache();
        $this->db->select('A.id, A.title, A.price');
        $this->db->from('articles A');
    }

    public function check_type($aTypeOfArticle){
        $this->db->where("A.type=".$aTypeOfArticle);
    }

    public function check_price($aMaxPrice){
        $this->db->where("A.price<=".$aMaxPrice);
    }

    public function get_result(){
        $this->db->stop_cache();
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
        $this->db->flush_cache();
    }

}
```